# How to load an html file onload in jquery

Tags: jquery

I just want to run this html file in jquery on the page load.

```
{$(document).ready('html.html');}
```

I'm missing a lot I think, but I'm still learning jquery and I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read more about jquery `load`:

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the
>   matched element.

This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), `.load()` sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Example:

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
   });
</script>
```

Comment: What do I connect the #result to?

Comment: Check the edit, you connect it to an HTML element with `id="result"`